# Django - order on @property gives "no such column"

Tags: django, django-models

I want to order a list based on a model property

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def client_orders(self):
        return len(Orders.objects.filter(client=self.user.email))
```

Then, to order my list of clients orders:

```
clients = sorted(Client.object.all(), key=lambda c: c.client_orders)
```

It gives me this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: accounts_client.client_orders
```

All my migrations are done. What am I missing there?

**Update**
I get this error because I have named by property with the same name of a former model field.

Comment: Have you tried with attrgetter. clients = sorted(Client.object.all(), key=attrgetter('client_orders')) ?

Comment: This code would not give that error. Show the full traceback.

Comment: Note that you're doing it wrong anyway - you have a relational database that knows how to count things, order them etc, and it will do so MUCH more efficiently than any python code you could write.  Use aggregation functions instead and sort on the aggregated values, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/